# how to loop a set amount of times

Tags: list, python-3.x, while-loop, counter

Im writing a code that simulates the game word scrabble. What im trying to do is that it asks the user to unscrabble the word, and if they fail at it once they get another chance and so on for 3 chances. after 3 chances the program should tell them that they couldn't guess it within the chances limit and the program should tell them the word.

```
rand_artist = artist_names[random.randrange(len(artist_names))]
tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    rand_input = enterbox("Unscrabble the following: {}".
            format(txt), "Word Scrabble")
    if rand_input != rand_artist:
        msgbox("Try again!", "Word Scrabble")
        tries +=1
    elif rand_input == rand_artist:
        msgbox("Congratulations! You guessed the word!")
        tries +=3
    elif tries > 2: 
        msgbox("You used up three chances! The word was {}".
                format(txt), "Word Scrabble!")
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your current code? If there are any error messages include them in your question.

Comment: and the error/question/doubt is ?

Comment: You should post something that can be run.  It is better to debug logic without using gui widgets.  If you are using tkinter, Label and Entry widgets would be better than popup boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code had several problems, some noted in my comment on the question.  The following works as you seem to want.

```
from random import choice, shuffle
artist_names = ['Renoir', 'VanGogh', 'Rembrant', 'Homer', 'Pyle',]
artist = choice(artist_names)
alist = list(artist)
shuffle(alist)
scram = ''.join(alist)

for tries in range(1, 4):
    guess = input("Unscrabble {}: ".format(scram))
    if guess == artist:
        print("Congratulations! You guessed the word!")
        break
    elif tries < 3:
        print("Try again!")
    else:
        print("Failed three chances! The word was {}.".format(artist))
```

Comment: would there be a way to use this without break?

Comment: `guessed = False` followed by `while tries < 3 and not guessed:`.  Your original code encoded `(not) guessed` as part of `tries`.  I think it cleaner and clearer to use two names for the two different concepts.

Comment: You did not specify 'without break' in your first post and I think what I answered is the better way to proceed.  But maybe tomorrow.